# Lets Encrypt DNS challenge using HTTP

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt, google-cloud-dns

I'm trying to setup a Let's Encrypt certificate on Google Cloud. I recently changed it from http01 to dns01 challenge type so that I could create Cloud DNS zones and the acme challenge TXT record would automatically be added.

Here's my certificate.yaml

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata: 
  name: san-tls
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: san-tls
  issuerRef: 
    name: letsencrypt
  commonName: www.evolut.net
  altNames: 
  - portal.evolut.net
  dnsNames:
    - www.evolut.net
    - portal.evolut.net
  acme: 
    config: 
    - dns01:
        provider: clouddns
      domains:
      - www.evolut.net
      - portal.evolut.net
```

However now I get the following error when I `kubectl describe certificate`:

```
 Message:               DNS names on TLS certificate not up to date: ["portal.evolut.net" "www.evolut.net"]
    Reason:                DoesNotMatch
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
```

More worryingly, when I `kubectl describe order` I see the following:

```
Status:
  Challenges:
    Authz URL:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/redacted
    Config:
      Http 01:
    Dns Name:  portal.evolut.net
    Issuer Ref:
      Kind:     Issuer
      Name:     letsencrypt
    Key:        redacted
    Token:      redacted
    Type:       http-01
    URL:        https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/redacted
    Wildcard:   false
    Authz URL:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/redacted
    Config:
      Http 01:
```

Notice how the `Type` is always http-01, although in the certificate they are listed under dns01.

This means that the ACME TXT file is never created in Cloud DNS and of course the domains aren't validated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related an issue related to the use of multiple domains. I suggest the use of two different namespaces. You can check an example in the following link:

[Failed to list *v1alpha1.Order: orders.certmanager.k8s.io is forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578527/failed-to-list-v1alpha1-order-orders-certmanager-k8s-io-is-forbidden)